# Expected number of moves across a square

Tags: expected-value

Given a square. Each vertex is connected to every other vertex. An ant is located at one of the vertices. There are breadcrumbs on every other vertex. I.e. 3 breadcrumbs, each at rest of the vertices. It will go to every other vertex with equal probability (⅓). What is the expected number of moves the ant will take to eat all the breadcrumbs?

Comment: Your efforts? What have you tried.

Comment: Very interesting, but what have you tried?

Comment: You could read about the coupon collector problem.  This is an example, where the ant has collected the first coupon at the start.

Comment: @RossMillikan , Hello Sir, I just read about the coupon collector problem and found the expected number of moves to be **E(X) = 3(1/3 + 1/2 + 1/1) - 1** **=** **5.5** ......Is this correct??

Comment: The $5.5$ is correct but the expression before it is not.  You should not be subtracting $1$.  It looks like you have understood the question correctly.

Comment: @RossMillikan : Thank you Sir